# Should the contents of a column acting as a primary key be interpretable or purely unique integers

Tags: database

I have the luxury of designing a database from scratch. When designing columns to act as unique keys should I just use unique integers or should I attempt to make the values interpretable. So if I had a lookup table of ward names in a hospital should the id column contain unique codes that in someway relate to the name of the ward or just unique integers?

Answer (score 1):

Resist the temptation to overload the id values with meaning. Use other attributes to store the info you're considering stuffing into the id.

Overloading the id with "meaning" is bad because:

- If the data being stuffed into the ID changes, so must your ID. ID's should **never** change
- If the data *type* of the data changes, you'll have a problem, for example:

  - If your ID is numeric, and the stuffed info changes from numeric to text, you'll have big problems
  - If the stuffed data changes from a simple field to a one-to-many child, your model will break
- What you believe has "important" meaning now may not be important in the future. Then your "specially encoded" data will become useless and a burden, even a serious restriction
- What currently "identifies" a product may change as the business evolves

If have seen this idea attempted many times, never successfully. In every case, the idea was scraped and [surrogate IDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) were introduced to replace the magic IDs, with all the risk and development cost associated with that task.

In my career,  have seen most of the problems listed above actually happen.

Comment: I sort of figured this out. My problem is that one can end up with tables that pretty much only contain IDs from other tables which is unreadable. Under those circumstances is it conventional to create a "readable" view with all the relevant joins.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a lookup table. Make your tables innodb and use referential integrity to join tables together. Your id columns should always be set as primary and should be set to auto increment. Never try to make up your own ids. You should really look at some tutorial on referential integrity and learn how to assoicate tables with other tables.